# How to fix GSON issue when obfuscating with Proguard?

Tags: java, javafx, gson, proguard, obfuscation

My proguard configuration file is like this.

```
    -injars E:\Workspace\Git\Sample/lib/AltifeatUI.jar
-outjars E:\Workspace\Git\Sample\lib/Feat.jar

-libraryjars C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars E:\git\space-feat\src\AltiFEATUI/lib/jfxrt.jar
-libraryjars C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_67/lib/ant-javafx.jar

-optimizationpasses 5   
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
-ignorewarnings
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-verbose
-flattenpackagehierarchy ''
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,images/*.jar,.version

-adaptclassstrings
-adaptresourcefilenames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-keepnames class com.google.gson.** {*;}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
@javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, com.altifeat.Main {
 public static *;
}

-keep public class com.altifeat.Main {
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.sun.** { *; }
-keep class javafx.** { *; }
-keep class netscape.javascript.** { *; }
-keep class test.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class np.** { *; }
```

When I execute the obfuscated jar, some functions are not working. I found that this is because of using gson.fromJson() method in my code. I tried adding logger statements before and after this. The one before this is getting printed and not the one after. I haven't obfuscated any classes in GSON jar. Please help.

Comment: -ignorewarnings remove this line find the exact problem

Comment: Warning: class [resources/classes/com/javafx/main/Main$1.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.javafx.main.Main$1]
 Warning: class [resources/classes/com/javafx/main/Main$2.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.javafx.main.Main$2]
 Warning: class [resources/classes/com/javafx/main/Main.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.javafx.main.Main]
 Warning: class [resources/classes/com/javafx/main/NoJavaFXFallback.class] unexpectedly contains class [com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback]

Getting this. I added -ignorewarnings because of this.

Comment: so use "-dontwarn com.javafx.main.**" in last line.

Comment: I dont see any meaningful warnings or errors. Build is successful though.

Comment: I have even tried putting gson.fromJson() part into a separate class and not obfuscating that class. Still it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which exception do you have?